In NPOI, appending a new sheet is corrupting the Excel file
I am required to create and save an Excel file, and subsequently append it by adding a new sheet. However, while this generates new files, attempting to append a new sheet leads to the corruption of the Excel document. I'm using same code for Create and Append.
    public int GenerateExcel()
   {
       string sheetName;
       string fileName = "C:\\Export\\NewFile.xlsx";

       XSSFWorkbook workbook;

       if (Path.Exists(fileName))
       {
           FileStream file1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
           workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file1);
           sheetName = "Append";
       }
       else
       { 
           workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
           sheetName = "Create";
       }
       
       ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(sheetName);
       
       sheet.CreateRow(0).CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(sheetName);

       using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
       {
           workbook.Write(fs1);
           fs1.Close();
       }

       using (FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("C:\\Export\\NewFile_WithCopy.xlsx", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
       {
           IWorkbook workbookToCopy = new XSSFWorkbook();

           workbook.GetSheet(sheetName).CopyTo(workbookToCopy, sheet.SheetName, true, true);

           workbookToCopy.Write(fs2);

           fs2.Close();
       }


       return 1;

   }

Excel Msg
Code runs with no issues,  but Excel file is getting corrupted.

Excel files are binary, you can't just "append" data to them. You can't do that in many text files too, like JSON or XML. You can only load the entire file, modify it, then save the entire file back. xlsx files are ZIP packages containing XML data, which means that modifying even a single byte invalidates the ZIP's checksum, thus corrupting the file.
